# Include node creation form error processForm

Tags: 8, forms

I am using the following code include a node creation form.

```
namespace Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class RegisterFriterieForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form
 */
class RegisterFriterieForm extends FormBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'register_friterie_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $entity = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
            'type' => node_type_load('friterie')->id(),
        ));
        // OPTIONAL - Set default values for node fields
        // $entity->set('field_machine_name', "value");
        $node_create_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity);

        // I can display it with this method, but I don't know how to delete
        // some fields.
//        $form['friterie'] = [
//            '#type' => 'container',
//            'form' => $node_create_form
//        ];
        $form['friterie'] = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => render($node_create_form),
            '#prefix' => '<div id="friterie-form">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>'
        );
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}

}
```

I get the following error.

> Warning: `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form\RegisterFriterieForm' does not have a method 'processForm' in `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->doBuildForm()` (line 979 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php).

I can fix it by changing `$form['friterie']` to a markup type; with the markup I then use `render($node_create_form)`. When I want to alter my form with `hook_form_alter()` it's a string and I cannot modify the form.

Comment: That is only one method; we need to see the full class you are using, and that contains that method.

Comment: i updated my post but the error is that i have no processForm function in my class but i dont know what is this method and what to write in... I started drupal 8 tuesday (there is a big lack of tutorials on the net...) In D7 i used field_form_attach() method to include node and user form and this was a great function. Why in D8 it's so hard...

Comment: I addressed this issue in the answer for your original question. The short answer is to unset the #process attribute from the subform.

Comment: The long answer is that when the form builder renders a form element it assumes it represents the main form object. In my answer I moved the #process array to the form state object and added a #process callback of my own that calls the ones saves in the form state.

Comment: Thanks, it's very interesting, i would like know more. How did you get so much knowlegde with D8 ? Have you follow some web lessons ?